# Basic Logarithms problems

Tags: logarithms

Can someone tell me how many digits would be there in-

$(2.5)^{200}$ and $6^{50}? $

I'm utterly confused where to begin from. Any help would be appreciable.

Comment: Do you understand that the result will not be a whole number ?

Comment: Yes but that's where the characteristics and mantessa will come in play right? Please tell me how to proceed

Comment: You will want to apply $ \ \log p^n \ = \ n \ \log p \ $ and the "number facts" that $ \ \log_{10} \ 2.5 \ \approx \ 0.4 \ $ and  $ \ \log_{10} \ 6 \ \approx \ 0.78 \ $ .

Comment: Hint: Given $x^y$, find $z$ such that $x^y={10}^z$. Do you (a) see how to do that, and (b) see how $z$'s your answer?

Answer (score 2):

$6^{50}=10^{50/\log_{6}(10)}\implies6^{50}$ has $\lceil{50/\log_{6}(10)}\rceil=39$ digits.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach  that shows the rule of ''characteristic'' and ''mantissa''

starting from:
$\log_{10} 2.5 \approx 0.3979$

we have:
$
\log_{10} (2.5)^{200} \approx 200 \cdot 0.3979 \approx 79.56=79+0.56
$

where $79$ is the characteristic and $0.56$ is the mantissa.

So:
$
(2.5)^{200}\approx10^{79+0.56}=10^{79}\cdot 10^{0.56}=3.6 \cdot 10^{79}
$